# Apply Css Using javascript Loop?

Tags: javascript, css, loops

I am trying to apply css to javascript using a function which has loop

```
this.addcss = function(ele , css){
    for(var k in css)
        ele.style[k] = css[k];
    return true;
}

this.addcss(bodyDiv,{"height":"auto" , "width":"400px auto" , "border":"solid 2px black"});
```

The Div `bodyDiv` is not empty.

This code is not working .
I am not getting any error in my console as well

I tried Doing this as well but didn't worked:

```
this.addcss = function(ele , css){
    for(var k in css)
        ele.style.k = css.k;
    return true;
}
```

Turns out the problem was with the element replacement:

earlier i was using this code to replace an element with other:

```
var Obj = element;
    if(Obj.outerHTML) { //if outerHTML is supported
        Obj.outerHTML=replacementHtml; ///it's
    }
    else { //if outerHTML is not supported, there is a weird but crossbrowsered trick
        var tmpObj=document.createElement("div");
        tmpObj.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
        ObjParent=Obj.parentNode; //Okey, element should be parented
        ObjParent.replaceChild(tmpObj,Obj); // here we placing our temporary data instead of our target, so we can find it then and replace it into whatever we want to replace to
        ObjParent.innerHTML = ObjParent.innerHTML.replace(ObjParent.innerHTML, replacementHtml);
    }
```

No i tried this:

```
element.parentNode.replaceChild(replacement, element);
```

And it worked.

Thanks for all the answers .

Comment: Did you inspect the element in DevTools?

Comment: what is bodyDiv? how did you get that element?

Comment: bodyDiv = document.createElement();

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not just setting the css inside of a class, and then just adding that class to the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working well, however I changed the `width` attribute, It can't have two values.

```js
var bodyDiv = document.createElement("DIV");

this.addcss = function(ele , css)
{
    for(var k in css)
        ele.style[k] = css[k];
}

this.addcss(bodyDiv,{"height": "auto", "width":"400px", "border": "solid 2px black"});

document.getElementById("placeholder").appendChild(bodyDiv);
```

```html
<div id="placeholder"></div>
```

Comment: If that's the case: width should probably be auto, and max/min-width could be set to 400px?  Add some flexibility.  Perhaps that was the approach he meant for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the content of bodyDiv correctly, e.g.

```
var bodyDiv = document.getElementById("myBodyDiv");
```

I have proved this works with a quick jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kitkit/gh7yxLey/

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this:

```
ele.style=k;
this.addcss = function(ele , css){
    for(var k in css)
        ele.style = k;
    return true;
}

this.addcss(bodyDiv,{"height:auto" , "width:400px auto" , "border:solid 2px black"});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to be working for me. Here's a working fiddle

```js
bodyDiv = document.createElement('div');

this.addcss = function(ele , css){
    for(var k in css)
        ele.style[k] = css[k];
    return true;
}

this.addcss(bodyDiv,{"height":"auto" , "width":"400px" , "border":"solid 2px black"});

document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(bodyDiv);
```

```html
<body>
  
</body>
```

I would suggest double checking the way your element is created and the way it is appended to the body.